# How to use autogenerated settings tab

Tags: android, settings

I was wondering if anyone of you could tell me how I can link an settingsactivity to the tab which you open when clicking at the three-points in the topcorner of the app. These 3 points were automatically generated; I never programmed anything to let them be there.

Could you guys please help?
Sorry for my bad English but I'm not a native-speaker

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess that you are referring to the overflow area of the action bar. In that case, you will want to:

- create a menu resource declaring the things you want in that menu (e.g., `res/menu/activity_main.xml`)
- inflate that resource in an `onCreateOptionsMenu()` of your activity (or fragment)
- respond to taps on your item in `onOptionsItemSelected()` of your activity (or fragment)

You will find out more about this process in the [Menus](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) and [Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) pages in the SDK documentation.